# List of XSLT instructions/functions that change the context node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

Does anyone know of a list of XSLT instructions/functions that change the context node?

For example, instruction like `for-each` is one of them.

Comment: `<xsl:for-each` is pretty much it, but it's enough. I wanted to change the context without having to write a new template. I found that `for-each`ing on a singular selection is what I needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The obvious XSLT 2.0 instructions that change the context are `for-each`, `apply-templates`, `for-each-group`, and `analyze-string`. But there's also, for example, `xsl:sort` and `xsl:key`.

In XPath, the operators `/` and `[]` change the context. There are no functions that change the context.

Comment: heys cool =D btw is it true to say that the only way to change the **current node** is for-each?

Comment: Update for XSLT 3.0: there's also now `xsl:iterate`, `xsl:source-document`, `xsl:merge`

Answer (score 3):

There are only two things in XSLT 1.0 that change the context and neither of them are functions. These are:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='some-test'/>
```

(which will lead to the selected nodes being processed, each one becoming the context node as it is processed)

and

```
<xsl:for-each select='some-test'/>
```

In XSLT 2.0, you also have

```
<xsl:for-each-group/>
```

(which sets the context node in slightly more complex way than `xsl:apply-templates` and `xsl:for-each`

Comment: apply-templates doesn't change the context node within the current template, it goes to a different template. As far as I know, xsl:for-each is the only one that can change the meaning of `.` inside a template.

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes. `xsl:apply-templates` itself does not change the context. It selects nodes for processing. The processing template itself sets the current node. However, it does lead to the context changing which was the point I was making :)